# With Data Fusion transform a BigQuery table (source, containing ARRAY/STRUCT) via Transform "Wrangler" to a corresponding "normalized" BigQuery table

Tags: normalization, google-cloud-data-fusion

**(1)** There is a BigQuery source-table like ...

```
column_name | is_nullable | data_type

OrderId     | YES         | STRING
items       | NO          | ARRAY<STRUCT<articleId STRING, quantity FLOAT64INT64>>
```

"OrderId" is supposed to be the Key from ralational table perspective.

**(2)** Now I'd like to normalize the ARRAY/STRUCT record to a separate table.
To achieve this I'm using the Transform "Wrangler".

**NOTE**: It's the "Wrangler" from the Transport section of Data Fusion's Studio! When trying to open the "Wrangler" via the hamburger menu, and selecting the BQ source table it's telling: *BigQuery type STRUCT is not supported.*

The output of the source-table is linked to the input of Wrangler.

In Wrangler I defined ...

- Input field name: *
- Precondition: false
- Directives / Recipe: keep combiOrderId,items,articleId,quantity
- Output Schema (Name | Type | Null):  -- (according to the source table, JSON attached below)

  `combiOrderId | string | yes
  items         | array  | no
    record [ {articleId | string | yes}, {quantity | float | yes} ]`

[Wrangler parameters screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVarm.png)

**(3)** The BQ sink table takes the Wrangler Output as Input Schema, and I defined the final schema as (Name | Type | Null)

`combiOrderId | string | yes
articleId | string | yes
quantity | float | yes`

Now, when running the pipeline (Preview mode), the following error message is logged:

> Problem converting into output record. Reason : Unable to decode array
>   'items'

(full message very below)

**Any hint or an alternative solution would be very welcomed :-)**

**Thank you.**

JSON of Wrangler's Output Schema:

```js
[
    {
        "name": "etlSchemaBody",
        "schema": {
            "type": "record",
            "name": "etlSchemaBody",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "combiOrderId",
                    "type": [
                        "string",
                        "null"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "items",
                    "type": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "type": "record",
                            "name": "a6adafef5943d4757b2fad43a10732952",
                            "fields": [
                                {
                                    "name": "articleId",
                                    "type": [
                                        "string",
                                        "null"
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "quantity",
                                    "type": [
                                        "float",
                                        "null"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Full (first) error log:

```js
java.lang.Exception: Stage:Normalize-items - Reached error threshold 1, terminating processing due to error : Problem converting into output record. Reason : Unable to decode array 'items'
 at io.cdap.wrangler.Wrangler.transform(Wrangler.java:412) ~[1576661389534-0/:na]
 at io.cdap.wrangler.Wrangler.transform(Wrangler.java:94) ~[1576661389534-0/:na]
 at io.cdap.cdap.etl.common.plugin.WrappedTransform.lambda$transform$5(WrappedTransform.java:90) ~[cdap-etl-core-6.1.0.jar:na]
 at io.cdap.cdap.etl.common.plugin.Caller$1.call(Caller.java:30) ~[cdap-etl-core-6.1.0.jar:na]
 at io.cdap.cdap.etl.common.plugin.WrappedTransform.transform(WrappedTransform.java:89) ~[cdap-etl-core-6.1.0.jar:na]
 at io.cdap.cdap.etl.common.TrackedTransform.transform(TrackedTransform.java:74) ~[cdap-etl-core-6.1.0.jar:na]
 at io.cdap.cdap.etl.spark.function.TransformFunction.call(TransformFunction.java:50) ~[hydrator-spark-core2_2.11-6.1.0.jar:na]
 at io.cdap.cdap.etl.spark.Compat$FlatMapAdapter.call(Compat.java:126) ~[hydrator-spark-core2_2.11-6.1.0.jar:na]
 at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:125) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
 at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:125) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
 at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434) ~[scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na]
 at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440) ~[scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na]
 at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439) ~[scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na]
 at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439) ~[scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na]
 at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:128) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
 at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:127) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
 at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1415) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
 at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.org$apache$spark$internal$io$SparkHadoopWriter$$executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:139) [spark-core_2.11-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
 at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:83) [spark-core_2.11-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
 at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78) [spark-core_2.11-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87) [spark-core_2.11-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109) [spark-core_2.11-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
 at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345) [spark-core_2.11-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_232]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_232]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_232]
Caused by: io.cdap.wrangler.api.RecipeException: Problem converting into output record. Reason : Unable to decode array 'items'
 at io.cdap.wrangler.executor.RecipePipelineExecutor.execute(RecipePipelineExecutor.java:102) ~[wrangler-core-4.1.3.jar:na]
 at io.cdap.wrangler.Wrangler.transform(Wrangler.java:384) ~[1576661389534-0/:na]
 ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.cdap.wrangler.utils.RecordConvertorException: Unable to decode array 'items'
 at io.cdap.wrangler.utils.RecordConvertor.decodeArray(RecordConvertor.java:382) ~[wrangler-core-4.1.3.jar:na]
 at io.cdap.wrangler.utils.RecordConvertor.decode(RecordConvertor.java:142) ~[wrangler-core-4.1.3.jar:na]
 at io.cdap.wrangler.utils.RecordConvertor.decodeUnion(RecordConvertor.java:368) ~[wrangler-core-4.1.3.jar:na]
 at io.cdap.wrangler.utils.RecordConvertor.decode(RecordConvertor.java:152) ~[wrangler-core-4.1.3.jar:na]
 at io.cdap.wrangler.utils.RecordConvertor.decodeRecord(RecordConvertor.java:85) ~[wrangler-core-4.1.3.jar:na]
 at io.cdap.wrangler.utils.RecordConvertor.toStructureRecord(RecordConvertor.java:56) ~[wrangler-core-4.1.3.jar:na]
 at io.cdap.wrangler.executor.RecipePipelineExecutor.execute(RecipePipelineExecutor.java:99) ~[wrangler-core-4.1.3.jar:na]
 ... 26 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Torsten: The easiest way to check what the error could be is to navigate from Wrangler. You can do this by following these steps,
1. Go to Wrangler connection <host>:<port>/cdap/ns/default/connections
2. Click on BQ source (or create a BigQuery connection)
3. Navigate to BQ table and click on it.
4. This will take you to wrangler workspace (tabbed view)
5. From there you can apply all the transformations and click "Create Pipeline"

After this point you should see your source and wrangler transform already configured. You can then add a sink and run preview to test if things wrk

Comment: To address your other point: Wrangler only supports array type in BQ source. It doesn't support reading STRUCT types from BigQuery. My guess would be thats why you are seeing this issue. https://issues.cask.co/browse/CDAP-15665

Answer (score 0):

**Adding the comment as answer.**

**Regarding debugging the error:**
The easiest way to check what the error could be is to navigate from Wrangler. You can do this by following these steps,

1. Go to Wrangler connection :/cdap/ns/default/connections
2. Click on BQ source (or create a BigQuery connection)
3. Navigate to BQ table and click on it.
4. This will take you to wrangler workspace (tabbed view)
5. From there you can apply all the transformations and click "Create Pipeline"

After this point you should see your source and wrangler transform already configured. You can then add a sink and run preview to test if things wrk

**To address your other point:** Wrangler only supports array type in BQ source. It doesn't support reading STRUCT types from BigQuery. My guess would be thats why you are seeing this issue. issues.cask.co/browse/CDAP-15665